# how to validate a checkbox with the style =display:none in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a checkbox as a required field. But I hide the checkbox using `display:none` CSS. So that the bootstrap form validation error message not showing. How can I show the error message?

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.option-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<input class="option-input" id="feature-checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="E-mail Login" />
<label class="feature-label" for="feature-checkbox1">
     <div id="feature-card" class="card" data-option-id="101" data-name="E-mail Login" data-price-min="200" data-price-max="400">
      <div class="card-content text-center">          
       <i id="feature-icon" class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
       <p>Login</p>          
      </div>
     </div>
    </label>
```

Comment: If it's a required field, why do you want to hide it?

Comment: Please share the JS code in charge of validation. It can be the root cause.

Comment: because I used a custom design for checkbox label and hide the checkbox field. So that entire card work as a checkbox

Comment: if u are hiding the checkbox then why writing so much styling for that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.control-label` class to label and wrap the elements(checkbox and label) in a div with a class `.input-group`.

Now adding `.has-error` on the input-group div turns it into red color.

use jquery or javascript to validate checkbox .

hope this helps..